# jQuery: Get JSON error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get certain elements from a JSON file but I'm just not able to do so, I've tried different ways, this is the JSON file:

```
// data.json
{
    "stuff": [
        {
            "userId": 1,
            "date": "19 Oct 2014",
            "content": "#New Hello on g.co/ABC",
            "entities": {
                "hashtags": ["#New"],
                "urls": ["g.co/ABC"]
            }
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "avatar": "/assets/avatar.jpg",
        "name": "Daniel"
    }
}
```

Now my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        //console.log(data);

        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            console.log(item.stuff.content); // I want to print 'content'
        });
    });
});
```

And all I get is an Uncaught error type:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stuff` is an array of object.

To access item of an array you have to access it via `index`

like this

```
console.log(data.stuff[0].content);
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/knner7en/2/)**</kbd>

May be you are iterating an object instead of array of object

If data is an object then try like this

```
$.each(data.stuff,function(i,item){
    console.log(item.content);
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/knner7en/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hello thank you for your help so far, doing the first recommendation of **item.stuff[0].content** I get _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined_ .... and for the second one I get _Uncaught ReferenceError: stuff is not defined_

Comment: @user3709532 can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: @user3709532 I delete my answer and we use Anik's one to solve the problem

Comment: @user3709532 i have created a fiddle this might help you : https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/knner7en/1/

Comment: thank you @AnikIslamAbhi that works, I forgot to change "stuff" to "item" when doing the _console.log_ command... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You `json` data is not an array. so you don't need to use each. But `stuff` is an array so take it's specific index or loop through it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
         console.log(data.stuff[0].content); 

         //or loop through like 
         //$.each(data.stuff,function(i,item){
         //   console.log(item.content);
         //});     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
   console.log(data['stuff'][0]['content']);
}
```

It is getting the stuff element of the JSON object then the first element of that pair, since the pair of key "stuff" is an array of JSON Objects. Then from that last JSON object, its grabbing content.